# Is anything nontrivial known about quotients of complexity classes?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

This question is just for fun and this is completely outside my area, so it's likely dumb; apologies in advance.

By a "quotient" I mean the following: suppose you have two complexity classes, $A \subseteq B$.  The quotient $B/A$ would consist of the equivalence classes of elements of $B$ under the relation $b \sim b'$ if you can solve $b'$ with a program from $A$ given input from an oracle for $b$, and vice-versa.  (I don't know if this concept has a name or is called something else; sorry.)

(To give the obvious example, the $P$ versus $NP$ problem asks whether $NP/P$ is trivial.)

Can anything interesting be said about this notion?

Comment: This is from long, long ago, but these are pretty closely related to the notion of 'reductions' and you might be able to find some information by searching under that name.  For instance, NP-completeness is actually the set of problems that are complete for NP 'under polynomial-time reductions', and there are many other types of reduction.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is extensively studied under oracle turing machines. 
Here is an example from [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521424267).

Let $EXPCOM$ = $\{<M,x,1^n>:$ M outpits 1 in $2^n$ steps.$\}$

Now consider $P^{EXPCOM}/EXP$ along with your definition.

Clearly $EXP\subseteq P^{EXPCOM}$. Now for two problem $(b,b')$ which is in $P^{EXPCOM}$
and if there is a polynomial time reduction from $b\leq_P b'$, then it creates a equivalence class since a program from $EXP$ (which just do the polynomial time reduction and queries the given oracle TM) can solve b'.